# Using addrow for MatrixCursor, how to add different object types?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursor, matrixcursor

I am trying to input data from a `List<ParseObject>` to a cursor. ParseObject documentation can be found [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html).

I found out that you can use MatrixCursor to do this, referring to helpful sites:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html

[How to insert extra elements into a SimpleCursorAdapter or Cursor for a Spinner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754973/how-to-insert-extra-elements-into-a-simplecursoradapter-or-cursor-for-a-spinner)

[How to create Cursor data without getting data from the DataBase in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860619/how-to-create-cursor-data-without-getting-data-from-the-database-in-android-appl)

My problem is, when I return the cursor from MyContentProvider.java, and I try to do a cursor.getFloat(), it returns a String and I cannot do DecimalFormat on it.

#### Question:

How do I put more than one kind of data type into the MatrixCursor using, addRow (Object[] columnValues)?

Method that uses Cursor data:

```
public void getData() {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(URI, null, mParseId, null, null);

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
    df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

    mTextview.setText(df.format(
        cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("number"))));
}
```

MyContentProvider.java:

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
  ......
  MatrixCursor mc = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { "_id", "title", "number" });

  mc.addRow(new String[] { ParseObject.getString("id"), ParseObject.getString("title"), ParseObject.getString("number") });
  return mc;
}
```

What I want to do in MyContentProvider.java:

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
  ......
  MatrixCursor mc = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { "_id", "title", "number" });

  mc.addRow(new String[] { ParseObject.getLong("id"), ParseObject.getString("title"), ParseObject.getDouble("number") });
  return mc;
}
```

Comment: "and I try to do a ParseObject.getDouble(), it returns a String"- you sure about that?

Comment: a sorry, I meant to say cursor.getFloat() returns a String, will edit my question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand your code samples, but I can answer on your main question

> How do I put more than one kind of data type into the MatrixCursor using, addRow (Object[] columnValues)?

Change array type from `String` to `Object`:

```
mc.addRow(new Object[] {1, "text", 0.666});
```